# cannot import from react-testing-library

Tags: react-testing-library

`render` is undefined when i

```
import { render } from 'react-testing-library'
```

into our project. seems that the same issue was raised [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/191) but wasn't resolved.

if i

```
import * as x from 'react-testing-library'
```

i get a big object for `x`, so the lib is there

everything works ok on a simple setup, but the imports are undefined when trying to use it into our existing project.

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of the error you got?

Comment: seems that the library can possibly conflict with some configurations for jest and its code will not run. https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/318